# vscode react-native typescript breakpoint not hit: source map

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, source-maps

I have been struggling with this problem for more that one year. I have filed an [issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/441). I have tried to apply the solution description there and from countless suggestions all over internet ([example](https://github.com/adrianhall/masterdetailtemplate)). Here is my configuration

```
node v8.9.1
npm 4.6.1
react-native-cli 2.0.1
react-native 0.54.2
vscode 1.21.1
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "default": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "start": "react-native start --transformer node_modules/react-native-typescript-transformer/index.js --sourceExts ts,tsx",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "0.54.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.0.40",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.52.18",
    "babel-jest": "23.0.0-alpha.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.2",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

No matter what I do, I can't get my typescript breakpoints (.tsx) hit, a little desperate here. Any help and assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the error messages I am getting:

./src/app.tsx

[image: app.tsx sourcemap breakpoint]

transpiled ./build/app.js

[image]

And finally here is my ./vscode/launch.json:

```
    "name": "debug android",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
    "type": "reactnative",
    "request": "launch",
    "platform": "android",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the `"outFiles"` attribute to your `launch.json` as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_source-maps)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I add this attribute, I get the warning: "Property outFiles is not allowed".
I think this attribute is used for a web react project (with chrome debugger) and not for a react-native application

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution?